# Javascript: save image into mysql and shows it later into html5

Tags: javascript, mysql, image, node.js, blob

Do not blame me about the method. I just doing practice and I woud like to reach the end.
So, I'm storing via Javascript node.js some images into a remote mysql table using a blob field.
Later I would like to retrieve the image and show it in a html5.
I'm getting mad about the encode/decode proces. I stored the image using each of the following methods `readAsDataURL(f); readAsBinaryString(f); readAsText(f);` but when I retrieve the image I'm unable to diplay it in the `image.src`.
**The only way** to do that is to load manually the image into blob field via *phpmyadmin* and later send the blob field to the html page using the following conversion:

```
var base64 = new Buffer(results[i].tile_image, 'binary').toString('base64');
client.emit('showTile', base64);
```

The question is: how does phpmyadmin load the binary files into a blob field? Or, using javascript how I have to load the image into a blob?

Comment: Have you checked out this [tutorial](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql/)?

Comment: Thanks, very useful. I almost did the same. At page 7 of the tutorial there is the file loader but it's in php and I do not know that language. How can I translate the $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])); line?

Answer (score 0):

Converted comment into answer

Check out this [tutorial](http://www.phpriot.com/articles/images-in-mysql/) on uploading images and storing them in MySQL.

To answer your question $imgData =addslashes (file_get_contents($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'])); can be broken down as such

[$_FILES](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) is an associative array of files uploaded to the document, in this case the image.  [$_FILES]

[files_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) reads the file into a string.  In this case it will store the binary data of the file into a string which can be inserted into the DB.

[addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php) escapes any characters that need to be escaped.

Comment: Got the picture. The problem is to find the right method to store the image into the MySQL blob field. I think I really near the solution but no way to get it. I found a funtion called dataURLtoBlob which seems to transform in the right way the image since the Blob size is the same of the image stored manually via phpmyadmin in the DB table. BUT as soon as I try to insert the Blob object into the db the size if the table field is 0. No way to insert the right value which is 16.4k. When I pass the Blob to the sql command do I need to transform it?

Comment: It sounds like you're on the right track.  Have you tried following the tutorial exactly?  Once they get the $imgData on page 7 that is just inserted into the column of type blob.  It looks like the function you reference is a javascript function.  You probably want to do this server side (php) as opposed to client side (javascript).  I recommend doing the tutorial exactly.  There's probably a small detail you're overlooking